# RecyclerView doesn't expand underneath the row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to obtain an effect similar to this on my `RecyclerView`

[image]

I've tried to Google I/O approach that is described on similar questions here. My adapter code looks as follows.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
    final boolean isExpanded = position == mExpandedPosition;
    itemViewHolder.mNotesTV.setVisibility(isExpanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    holder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1 : position;
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    });
}

private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView mNotesTV;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mNotesTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notesTV);
    }
}
```

The `xml` file for the `TextView` I'm trying to expand looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notesTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Details" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The `xml` file with the `RecyclerView` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/historyLV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And what I get, instead of the effect shown above (`RecyclerView` item expands and underneath are the desired items), I just get my `TextView` inside the actual row instead of below.

[image]

Comment: you only have a textView in your row. what else are you expecting to see in the row? put some other views (maybe another text view or two) as well and check?

Comment: Can't I implement some code with a `LinearLayout` with `GONE` visibility that will automatically be placed below the row?

Comment: Which row are you talking about? Are you saying you want to inflate an extra row below the row which was clicked? If so, you'll need to add another item into the adapter's data source and `notifyDataSetChanged` or something. And I would say that it would be a bad approach even if it were possible. The best way would be to include all the views inside the viewHolder layout and set the views' visibility `GONE` or `VISIBLE` based on whether the row was clicked. That way, any item in the list could expand or collapse according to whether it was clicked.

Comment: The latter is actually what I was trying to achieve, my `TextView` has visibility set to `GONE` and `VISIBLE` when clicked, but I'm still unsure how to make that `TextView` appear below my row in my `RecyclerView`

Comment: I still don't get what you mean by "below my row". :( From the code you posted and from what I understand by "row", it looks to me like the only thing you have in a "row" is the `TextView`, so if you make it gone, the row won't show at all. Can you post screenshots of what your row looks like expanded vs collapsed and what it should ideally look like? By "should look like", I don't mean the screenshot of the dialer app. I mean a screenshot of your own app/layout preview.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to achieve something like [this](https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout/blob/master/images/recycler.gif), where "Tap to expand" is my "02 Mar. 2018" in my screenshot and "Content" is "Details".

Comment: Okay I'll post an answer for you. If it works for you, accept it. If not, we can take up further conversation in chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't already have a layout for your `viewholder`, make one like the one below. Change the IDs and colors according to your preference:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/alwaysVisible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:text="02 Mar, 2018"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/conditionallyVisible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:text="Details"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Next, inflate it in your adapter like this (assuming the above layout is called `item_layout`:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

In your `viewholder` class, get both the `TextView`s in the above layout like this:

```
private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView mDateTV;
    TextView mDetailsTV;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mDateTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.alwaysVisible);
        mDetailsTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.conditionallyVisible);
    }
}
```

In `onBindViewHolder`, do the following:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
    final boolean isExpanded = position == mExpandedPosition;
    itemViewHolder.mDetailsTV.setVisibility(isExpanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    holder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1 : position;
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    });
}
```

That's all. I hope you can get this to work.

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your requirement is make expandable recyclerview.
You can check this library https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

Comment: I was under the impression that I can achieve the effect shown above (the phone app) without any library and just using Google I/O approach

Comment: Check this file, you can make same thing.
https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view/blob/master/expandablerecyclerview/src/main/java/com/thoughtbot/expandablerecyclerview/ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter.java